# In iOS swift Json Parsing How to Pass Parameters in post method

Tags: swift

Here I have Tried to Sign Up the App Using Mobile Number but I cant do in correct format,I have error in Json parsing for signup the app.

Here I give the code what i am tried,

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://app.mycompany.in/gcm/test_slim.php/register")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)

var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?
var reponseError: NSError?

var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

// create some JSON data and configure the request

let jsonString = "json=[{\"gsm_number\":\(Mobile),\"name\":\(Name),\"email\":\(Email),\"status\":\(Status),\"ver_code\":,\"profile_picture\":,\"device_id\":,\"gcm\":,\"is_register\":,\"thumb_image\":,\"user_baground_img\":}]"

request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// send the request
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

// look at the response
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    println("HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    println("jsonString: \(jsonString)")
    var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let VerificationcodeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("verificationcodeViewController") as UIViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VerificationcodeViewController, animated: true)
} else {
    println("No HTTP response")
    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Error!"
    alertView.message = "Error. & Some Problem was Found"
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.show()
}
```

Comment: Can you post relevant error here?

Comment: Please mention the error.

Comment: syntax error was occur

Comment: I made a mistake in pass parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have empty keys, try this :

```
let parameters = [
    "gsm_number" : Mobile,
    "name" : Name,
    "email" : Email,
    "status" : Status,
]

let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)

let jsonString = "json=\(NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You jsonString does not conform to the JSON syntax.

1. You can't have `json=` at the beginning, `=` isn't an allowed separator in JSON, use `:`
2. You need to wrap the string variables with double quotes (and escape them)
3. You can't have empty keys like that with just the value missing, you have to use `null`

Example of valid string for your variables:

```
let jsonString = "[{\"gsm_number\":\(Mobile),\"name\":\"\(Name)\",\"email\":\"\(Email)\",\"status\":\(Status),\"ver_code\":null}]"
```

Or with a 'json' key at the beginning like you had:

```
let jsonString = "{\"json\":[{\"gsm_number\":\(Mobile),\"name\":\"\(Name)\",\"email\":\"\(Email)\",\"status\":\(Status),\"ver_code\":null}]}"
```

Put this in a Playground and show the Assistant Editor in the "View" menu, it will help you understand:

```
let Mobile = 42
let Name = "James"
let Email = "test@test.com"
let Status = 200
let jsonString = "[{\"gsm_number\":\(Mobile),\"name\":\"\(Name)\",\"email\":\"\(Email)\",\"status\":\(Status),\"ver_code\":null}]"
let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

**Swift 1**

```
var err: NSError?
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &err) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
if err != nil {
    println(err)
} else {
    println(json![0]["status"]!)
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
do {
    if let data = data,
      let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        if let status = json[0]["status"] as? Int {
            print(status)
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```